# Having problems running a Simple C file, .. fatal error: sdkddkver.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, mingw

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main () {
    printf("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

im getting this error in my terminal

```
PS D:\> gcc D:\HELLOWRLD.C
In file included from c:\mingw\include\_mingw.h:73:0,
                 from c:\mingw\include\stdio.h:56,
                 from D:\HELLOWRLD.C:1:
c:\mingw\include\w32api.h:59:23: fatal error: sdkddkver.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sdkddkver.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
```

I tried reinstalling Vs code and MinGW but still the same error